# I get this in all my projects i dont know why and what is this how to fix it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In every projects I get when open a file  last night I write a code  but to day I start android studio I get this when I open other projects same thing is happening to some files

[image: check this image you can better understand]

Comment: try invalid caches and restart

Comment: i try but same issue

Comment: it this happen with all of the files ?

Comment: no some files in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted .gradle, cache, folder from c drive issue is not fixed but When I delete android studio  and reinstall android studio this issue is fixed my code is showing and app works normally

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your studio crashed. You need to clean your android studios cache folder. It is located at

On Windows: `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches`

`.AndroidStudio4.0` - choose your latest android's version here

close your studio first. Then delete this cache folder. After then restart your studio project. It will looks perfect after restarting.

Comment: i do but same issue

Comment: then remove your project's .build and .idea folders too.  Removing cache of studio is best solution. You need to remove it from your latest android studio's version

Comment: same issue i do all steps

Answer (score 0):

try `Window + R` cmd will open enter the `%temp%` and call cache will open select all then delete it.

delete the test folder from your project it will work. If you will delete the test folder it will not affect you remaining project. If it's not working inform me

Comment: same issues I don't know why

Comment: delete the test folder from your project it will work. If you will delete the test folder it will not affect you remaining project. If it's not working inform me.